# Writing update Query for updating a column based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I had written a query like this.

```
Update Dynamic_Grid 
set TRIAL=(Select Trial from TEMP) 
where UsrCode='ll1' 
and ColumnName=(Select ColumnName from TEMP)
```

It is throwing error. Can anyone please try to correct it?

Comment: What is an error? Describe `Dynamic_Grid` and `TEMP` pls.

Comment: how are the records `Select Trial from TEMP` related with this condition `where UsrCode='ll1'`?

Comment: If `TEMP` contains more than 1 row, your two sub-queries are returning more than one row.  This is not allowed.  But, to be sure, why not include the error message for us to see?  We're not psychic...

Answer (score 0):

most probably the sub-queries return more than one records...

these two queries should return only one value..

```
Select Trial from TEMP
Select ColumnName from TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set only one value for `TRIAL`. `Select Trial from TEMP` can return multiple values. So you should give a specific value in `set`.
You can use this:-

```
Update Dynamic_Grid 
set TRIAL='some value' 
where UsrCode='ll1' 
and ColumnName IN(Select ColumnName from TEMP)
```